# Auto scaling y-axis

Tags: quickchart

## Version 1

If I do the following in PowerShell:

```
$json = @"

{
    "chart": {
        "data": {
            "labels": [
                "2022-06-30",
                "2022-07-01",
                "2022-07-05",
                "2022-07-06",
                "2022-07-07"
            ],
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        5801404000000.0,
                        6060626000000.0,
                        6085791000000.0,
                        6035882000000.0,
                        6053350000000.0
                    ],
                    "label": "Net Liquidity"
                }
            ]
        },
        "options": {
            "scales": {}
        },
        "type": "bar"
    }
}

"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 'https://quickchart.io/chart' -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -OutFile C:\temp\test-2.png

Start-Process C:\temp\test-2.png
```

I get the following:

[image]

Looks good! Note that the y-axis is scaled appropriately.

## Version 2

However, if I do the following instead:

```
$json = @"

{
    "chart": {
        "data": {
            "labels": [
                "2022-06-30",
                "2022-07-01",
                "2022-07-05",
                "2022-07-06",
                "2022-07-07"
            ],
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        5801404000000.0,
                        6060626000000.0,
                        6085791000000.0,
                        6035882000000.0,
                        6053350000000.0
                    ],
                    "label": "Net Liquidity"
                }
            ]
        },
        "options": { },
        "type": "bar"
    }
}

"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 'https://quickchart.io/chart' -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -OutFile C:\temp\test-2.png

Start-Process C:\temp\test-2.png
```

I get the following:

[image]

Note that the y-axis now starts at 0.

## Differences

Version 1 uses:

```
"options": {
            "scales": {}
        },
```

while version 2 uses:

```
"options": { },
```

## Question

Is this a bug in quickchart? Or is this behaviour intentional? If so, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickChart sets `ticks.beginAtZero` by default if the `scales` object is not set.  This is an unfortunate inconsistency with the vanilla Chart.js v2 renderer, but it persists for backwards compatibility reasons (here's a [code pointer](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart/blob/master/lib/charts.js#L286) to the open source version).

You can avoid this by setting `options.scales` yourself (as you observed), or by using Chart.js v3 which does not include any default behavior.